# Leaflet polyline is displayed wrongly in certain zoom levels after implementing an offset

Tags: javascript, leaflet, polyline

I'm currently working on the following map. It contains different polylines that get an offset (through the Leaflet Polyline Offset plugin) if their route is already featured in the map. As you can see everything works fine in higher zoom levels. The problem is that Leaflet somehow displays the lines with an offset wrongly when a lower zoom level is chosen. Then the line gets some ugly rings at certain points. The lines get displayed correctly if I choose a lower offset, yet it doesn't look like I want it to. Is this a common problem or does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: Zoom level 13]

[image: Zoom level 12]

```
    function drawGeoJSONFeature(feature) {
        var featureGroup = L.featureGroup();
        var geometryArray = getAllGeometriesFromFeature(feature);

        for(var i = 0; i < geometryArray.length; i++) {
            if(!usedLineIDs.includes(geometryArray[i].lineID)) {
                usedLineIDs.push(geometryArray[i].lineID);
                var coords = turf.getCoords(geometryArray[i]);
                var swappedCoords = lnglatTolatlng(coords);
                var layer = L.polyline(swappedCoords, {color: feature.properties.lineColor, weight: 4}).addTo(featureGroup);
            } else {
                usedLineIDs.push(geometryArray[i].lineID);
                var coords = turf.getCoords(geometryArray[i]);
                var swappedCoords = lnglatTolatlng(coords);
                var layer = L.polyline(swappedCoords, {color: feature.properties.lineColor, weight: 4, offset: 4}).addTo(featureGroup);
            }
        }
        featureGroup.addTo(line);
    }
```

Best regards

Comment: This is a [known bug in Leaflet.PolylineOffset](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineOffset/issues/1).